# Can any $n$ number of linearly independent vectors build the basis of a vector space on $\Bbb R^n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm trying to understand how many bases there can be in a vector space. According to my understanding so far, for example in the vector space $\Bbb R^2$ every pair of linearly independent vectors can build a basis for that vector space. So, generally speaking, can any number $n$ of linearly independent vectors $\{v_1, v_2,...v_n\}$ make up a generator for the vector space $V \in \Bbb R^n$?

Comment: yes.  Try an induction proof on the number of dimensions.

Comment: Do you mean  $V\cong \Bbb R^n $?

Comment: There are two questions. One in the title and one in the text below. Since $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ you need only $n$ linear independent vectors. Further there are infinite many bases in this vector space.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as the definition of a basis is a linearly independent spanning set (at least in most books).

See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/986257/does-every-linearly-independent-set-of-n-vectors-in-rn-forms-a-basis-in-rn) post.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working over $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$, you will have infinitely many bases, because you can just take (nontrivial) scalar multiples of basis vectors to get distinct bases.